# "Toggle Window Fullscreen" Hotkey missing in 2.8?

Tags: interface

On 2.79 i used to click alt+F11 if i remember correctly.On 2.8 i cannot find,even on Preferences/Keymap tab,a way to check or assign a key to this specific command..

Only way to toggle it is from Window topbar,as in picture

[image]

I even tried to search on keymap the word "full",and this is the result,that specific command is missing it seems...Is it even possible ?Is there another way i can manually assign it ?Cant find anything online about this specific command

[image]

Comment: You are looking at it: Ctrl Spacebar will maximize a window. Ctrl+Alt+Spacebar will show the window with no menus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Window menu, right click on "Toggle Window Fullscreen", then select "Assign Shortcut". Press the shortcut you want, and it's done.

Of course, this works with every menu element.